# Orbit Slider (Foundation) Height Calculation Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am working for a client with an older version of Foundation. They are still using the built in Orbit Slider. That particular technology is now deprecated. However, I'm hoping someone here will know what may be occurring.

The error is this:

Orbit slider assigns a height element to the slider through an inline style that scales with page width. However, it seems to be detecting the width or calculating slider height incorrectly.

Note that style="height: 26px;"

**Issue**

[image]

Immediately upon scaling the page, it pulls the correct height.

Here is the front-end code I am using:

```
    <div class="mobile-list-slider-block"> 

    <ul id="mobile-list-slider" class="example-orbit" data-orbit>

      <li>
        <img nopin="nopin"  src="/localImages/mobile-slider-placeholder.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <img nopin="nopin"  src="/localImages/mobile-slider-placeholder.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <img  nopin="nopin"  src="/localImages/mobile-slider-placeholder.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
      </li>

    </ul>

    </div>
```

Any and all help would be kindly appreciated!

Comment: is the height of the orbit slider set from css?

Comment: After a fashion yes, however it is calculated via JS.

Comment: hi there, what was your solution for this issue?